# r does not show specified dates on x-axis

Tags: r

I used the following to generate a histogram

```
mi= 1425168014.519
ma= 1427919527.540
b=mi+rnorm(2000,sd=1)*(ma-mi)
hist(as.POSIXct(b, origin="1970-01-01"),breaks=50, freq = TRUE,axes=F)
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-04-01"), by="1 days"), format="%d %b %y")
```

But the specified dates are not shown in entirety. It only shows as minor ticks. I want it to be shown as labels.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to fit a lot of text into a really small area, and R hides the bits that will overlap.
A solution: http://www.r-bloggers.com/rotated-axis-labels-in-r-plots/

Comment: do you mind giving a complete solution for this? Thank you. :)

Comment: I am still not able to get it to work. so would really like your full solution. Thank you. :)